# how to remove rows with sequential digits in pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to remove the rows from a dataframe which contains sequential digits such as 1234 or 6789 ...

```
# Define regular expression pattern for sequential digits

pattern = r'\{3,}'
mask = df1['prix'].str.contains(pattern)
df_filtered = df1[mask]

print(df_filtered)
```

I tried this code but it returns the same data and when i tried this one before

```
pattern = r'\d{3,}'
df1['prix'] = df1['prix'].astype(str) 
mask = df1['prix'].str.contains(pattern)
if mask.any(): 
    print("There are rows with sequential digits.")
else:
    print("There are no rows with sequential digits.")
```

it returns that the data have sequential digits

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `df['text']` please?

Comment: 0         58500
1         35000
2         57000
3         23500
4         16000
          ...  
129765    36500
129766    19700
129771    22000
129777    12800
129780    31000 @Corralien here is it

Comment: Update the string in question. As said by @timgeb, this isn't regex problem, whereas you should write a separate abstraction that identifies whether a string has digits in ascending order or not...

Comment: You want to remove rows whose has at least 3 consecutive digits? increasing or decreasing or both?

Comment: yes @Corralien yes delete rows with at least 3 digits and in both situation

Comment: If the number of consecutive digits is just 3 then you can actually generate combinations for those using itertools and write a function that verifies if it is ascending and finally join all those with "|" finally passing that to str.contains(...). There will be a total of 10*9*8 sequential combinations including both ascending and descending order

Comment: @KayvanShah i have large number of rows so and thats why i'm putting at least 3 digits

Comment: @KayvanShah. There are only 16 combinations 012, 123, 234, etc

Comment: @Corralien Yeah incorrect calculation

Comment: def has_ascending_order(num):
    num_str = str(num)
    return all(num_str[i] <= num_str[i+1] for i in range(len(num_str)-2))

# Apply the function to the 'prix' column and filter the DataFrame
df_filtered = k[k['prix'].apply(has_ascending_order)] 
df_filtered i used this code now but it gives me so incorrect values like this 1350    
1250      
12222     
1550      
22250     
15678     
2350      
2450     
22350     
39999     2
16999     2
24990     
17999     
44450     
26999     
22499     
24999     1
1253      1
45799

Comment: @HadilBrahem, I still can't understand what your use case is.

Comment: it didnt work exactly too @Corralien . thank you everyone for the efforts ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
pattern = '|'.join([f'{i}{i+1}{i+2}' for i in range(0, 8, 1)]
                 + [f'{i}{i-1}{i-2}' for i in range(9, 1, -1)])
mask = df['prix'].astype(str).str.contains(pattern)

out = df[~mask]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
   prix
3  1379

>>> pattern
'012|123|234|345|456|567|678|789|987|876|765|654|543|432|321|210'

>>> mask
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: prix, dtype: bool

>>> df
   prix
0  1234  # drop (123)
1  6789  # drop (678)
2  4563  # drop (456)
3  1379  # keep
```